# Tiling textures with non power of two resolution

Tags: textures

I have a 300x600 pixels texture.

I can tile (uvmap) any texture of 256x256 pixel. But I can't tile 300x600, because it doesn't repeat. How can I solve this?

Comment: you should be more specific and give more details, what software package are you using?

Comment: We are using Threejs.